# Inheriting generic member functions

Tags: c++, c++17, crtp, member-functions

I am trying to transfer the definitions and declarations of templated member functions from a base class to derived classes. The catch is that some of the behaviour in those functions depends on the class, basically static polymorphism. I was recommended to use CRTP, which works great for the most part. 
However, if I want to inherit from a class that already inherited from my CRTP base class I have an issue. Consider the following code:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct CRTP
{
    template<typename TypeRHS>
    Derived& operator+=(const TypeRHS& rhs) 
    {
        // do something
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public CRTP<Derived<T>> {};

template<typename T>
struct DerivedDerived : public Derived<T> {};
```

If I call `+=` on `DerivedDerived<T>` it will return a type of `Derived<T>`. Is there a way I can solve this problem. I simply want to avoid having to redeclare/redefine all member functions within all classes. As far as free functions go, I have just templated those, but member functions have proven to be an issue.

I have updated my question with Brian's suggestion. Note that multiple inheritance causes ambiguities as to which function should be called - the one from `CRTP<DerivedDerived<T>>` or the one from `Derived<T>`:

```
template<typename T>
struct DerivedDerived : public Derived<T>, public CRTP<DerivedDerived<T>> {};
```

Comment: Why not `struct DerivedDerived : public CRTP<DerivedDerived<T>>`?

Comment: @Brian Because I want `DerivedDerived` to inherit also things defined in `Derived`.

Comment: Then, can you use multiple inheritance?

Comment: @Brian Seems to cause ambiguities with which function should be called.

Comment: Can you just insert a `using` declaration in the derived classes to bring the parent class method names into the scope of the derived classes? (One `using` declaration for each parent class method name that you want to pull into its scope.)

Comment: @phonetagger I can, but I still need the function to return the correct type. Also I have more than 30 member functions, at that point I might as well use a macro to redefine those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, the most general and modular solution I could come up with was actually separating the relevant parts I needed to inherit in `DerivedDerived` from `Derived` into their separate class, and then `Derived` can inherit those as well as the CRTP class, and then the same can be done for `DerivedDerived` effectively putting the two at the same level in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You need a CRTP that derives from Derived to be used by DerivedDerived

```
template<typename T>
struct CRTP
{
    template<typename TypeRHS>
    T& operator+=(const TypeRHS& rhs) 
    {
        // do something
        return static_cast<T&>(*this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public CRTP<Derived<T>> {
};

template<typename T>
struct CRTPForDerived : public Derived<T>
{
    template<typename TypeRHS>
    T& operator+=(const TypeRHS& rhs) 
    {
        // do something
        return static_cast<T&>(*this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct DerivedDerived : public CRTPForDerived<DerivedDerived<T> > 
{};
```

Comment: No other way than to redefine the function again? I am using CRTP in the first place to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of arithmetic operators, you can work around the problem by declaring the operator outside of the class/struct. In this case, no CRTP construct is needed:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Replaces template<typename> struct CRTP;
struct MyOperatorsBase {

};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public MyOperatorsBase {

};

template<typename T>
struct DerivedDerived : public Derived<T> {

};

// Overload "a += b" defined only if "a" derives from MyOperatorsBase.
template<typename RetType, typename RhsType>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<MyOperatorsBase,RetType>,RetType&> operator +=(RetType& lhs, const RhsType& rhs) {
    // do something.
    return lhs; // no downcasting static_cast needed, which is nice
}
```

#### [Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WZd12UfvzYqDK5sT)